# Get version of Composer package(s) in PHP, without using the command line

Tags: php, composer-php

Is there a way to get the version for a package installed with Composer, and which is currently used by an application, without invoking `composer show -i` or anything similar?

I want to determinate the versions currently used by the application and and show an alert if some packages need to be updated, and eventually auto update.

Comment: Do you mean from within your app? The only interface with composer is via cli, so it is hard to know what you are asking.

Comment: I want to get the version for package 'x/y' from script.

Comment: Have you looked at [exec](http://php.net/exec) and related functions?

Comment: That is what I wanted to avoid. Anyhow I found a solution that is a fair solution as composer doesn't provide this functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the current task, I think the appropriate solution will be the following.

Composer creates a *installed.json* file under *vendor/composer*, which contains all the information about the installed packages, as they are defined.

The file looks something similar to this.

```json
[
    {
        "name": "vendor_X/package_Y",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "version_normalized": "1.1.0.0",
        "source": {},
        "dist": {},
        "require": {},
        "require-dev": {},
        other data about the package
    },
    {"..other package's data..": ""},
    {"...": ""}
]
```

A simple solution will be using the following code.

```php
$data = array();
$packages = json_decode(file_get_contents('../vendor/composer/installed.json'));
 // Assuming that the project root is one level above the web root.
foreach ($packages as $package) {
    $data[$package['name']] = $package['version'];
}
    
// Make a cURL request to packagist.org to get the package data
// https://packagist.org/packages/vendor_X/package_Y.json
// The output is something like the following
/*
{
    "package": {
        "name": "omnipay/dummy",
        "versions": {
            "dev-master": {},
            "v1.1.0": {},
            "v1.0.0": {}
        },
        "type": "library",
    }
}
*/

$packagist = json_decode($packagist_reponse_as_json);
if (strcmp($data['vendor_X/package_Y'], $packagist['package']['versions'][1]) < 0) {
  // Fire a composer update, send email alert, show notification, or call the president.
}
```

The solution above is the simplest and a little ugly, but it shows the key points, namely, where to get local versions for packages and how to get the package versions from Composer.
A more practical solution should employ caching and should not be done during normal application operation; a better solution would be using a cron job.